# Using Razor to generate Angular2 templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angular, razor

I am trying to use Razor to generate the html used in an Angular template. I am using Angular v 2.0.0. I have a Contract.cshtml that looks like:

```
<script>
   System.import('contract.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
<my-contract>
    <h1>Hello {{name}} this is a quick starter for angular 2 app</h1>
</my-contract>
```

A Contract.ts that looks like

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ContractModule } from './app/Contract/contract.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ContractModule);
```

A contract.component.ts that looks like:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ContractComponent }  from './contract.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ ContractComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ ContractComponent ]
})
export class ContractModule { }
```

And a contract.component.ts that looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-contract'
 })
export class ContractComponent  { 
    public name = 'Nigel Findlater';
    consturctor() {} 
}
```

When I run this I get

```
Error: Error: No template specified for component ContractComponent    
        at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeDirective (http://localhost:2600/lib/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13476:21)                at RuntimeCompiler._createCompiledTemplate (http://localhost:2600/lib/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16869:210)
            at eval (http://localhost:2600/lib/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16807:43)
            at Array.forEach (native)
            at eval (http://localhost:2600/lib/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16805:50)
            at Array.forEach (native)
            at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:2600/lib/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16804:45)
            at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:2600/lib/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16741:39)
            at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:2600/lib/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16732:23)
            at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:2600/lib/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6954:29)
        Evaluating http://localhost:2600/contract.js
        Error loading http://localhost:2600/contract.js
```

I think the error is in contract.component.ts, but I don't know how not to specify a template here

Comment: In your my-contract component you would have a `template` or `templateUrl` specified in the `@Component` decorator. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html

Comment: I would like to use contract.cshtml to generate the template. If I use templateUrl I Need to use an html file and if I use template I have to specify the html directly in the ts. Should I be using something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular2 is not designed to be used with Razor generated templates. It is best to allow Angular2 to handle all the routing and not use MVC because this adds an unnecessary dependency which makes the project harder to test.

Answer (score 0):

I use Angular to offload a lot of work from the server to the client and host complex websites using much less resources. Those websites are not SPAs. 
In that context it can be really useful to use ASP.NET router and razor generated templates (sometimes precompiled).
The only problem I faced in using razor generated templates in Angular was the way **webpack** was configured.
After removing the **angular2-template-loader** everything worked smoothly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, in big websights it is easier not to have everything in 1 SPA. I was trying to take an approach that I had used in Angular 1.x where it is possible to use the ASP.NEt routing only and use the Anguar as a kind of VM in the browser. This does not work,

Comment: Well, I did that with Angularjs  (1.x) and I am doing the same thing with Angular 2 and 4 without any problem.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the solution, then we can discuss it.